# Nil Error While Running

Tags: swift3, xcode8, option-type, unwrap

i am working on TODO app,it was all completed and was running well but suddenly it begins to give an error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".Need Some Guide!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var tasks : [Task] = [ ]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    getdata()

    tableView.reloadData() 
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tasks.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    let task  = tasks[indexPath.row]

    if task.isimportant{
        cell.textLabel?.text = " ★   \(task.name!)"

    }else{
        cell.textLabel?.text = task.name!
    }

    return cell
}

func getdata() {
    let context =  (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    do{
    tasks = try  context.fetch(Task.fetchRequest())
    }
    catch {
        print ("Failed!")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The only optional you seem to be unwrapping is `task.name`, are you sure this value is not nil? You could try adding a breakpoint either in the `getdata()` method or `cellForRow:at:` to ensure the data is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1):

You should always avoid unwrapping optionals with an `!` because of the danger of encountering a runtime error if the optional is missing.  Try the following:

```
let taskName = task.name ?? "No name"
if task.isimportant{
    cell.textLabel?.text = " ★   \(taskName)"
}else{
    cell.textLabel?.text = taskName
}
```